# How can i use one node as a datanode in multiple hadoop clusters

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, cluster-computing, namenode, bigdata

I want to use one computer as a data node in two different hadoop clusters. I tried changing the ports, but that did not work. Please tell me if there are any port changes needed.

Comment: Which distribution are you using?

Comment: hi vgunnu, sorry for delay. I'm using hadoop2.7.2, spark 1.6.2

Answer (score 0):

If you have one 'box' that you want to use as 2 computers, you could consider running 2 virtual machines on it.

This is probably not the only way, but I am quite confident that it will work because I have seen 2 VMs in a cluster before.